# Could not find main class while using db2triples (Maven Project)

Tags: java, maven

I have compiled and made an executable jar file for db2triples program. I am using the following command for executing the jar file.

```
java -cp target/dependency/*.jar:target/db2triples-1.0.3-SNAPSHOT.jar  net.antidot.semantic.rdf.rdb2rdf.main.Db2triples
```

The main class has not been defined in the MANIFEST.MF file, therefore, I am explicitly defining it in the command.
The `net.antidot.semantic.rdf.rdb2rdf.main.Db2triples` is the location of the main class in the target/classes directory.

I am using Windows operating system.

Update:
After using semicolon the following error crops up:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/cli/ParseException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2693)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3040)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3010)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1776)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.cli.ParseException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 7 more
```

Comment: In windows use ; (semicolon) instead of :

Comment: If I use semicolon, I get the NoClassDefFoundError as updated in the question description

Comment: You should add commons-cli.jar to your dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

You need to either run the command from the `target/classes` directory or add the `target/classes` directory to your `-cp` list.